# Use cygwin as the mex compiler in matlab

Tags: matlab, g++, cygwin, mingw, mex

I have set cygwin as the mex compiler for MATLAB 2016b by setting the environment variable **MW_MINGW64_LOC** to be **G:\cygwin64**. I then tested some simple examples. The g++ in cygwin works fine as a compiler. However, when I call the compiled mexw64 function, matlab crashes and the error message is as follows:

```
MATLAB crash file:C:\Users\yh\AppData\Local\Temp\matlab_crash_dump.6792-1:


------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Access violation detected at Mon Jan 08 19:18:18 2018
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled - No sandbox or build area path
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Default Encoding    : windows-1252
  Deployed            : false
  Graphics card 1     : NVIDIA ( 0x10de ) NVIDIA Quadro K1100M Version 21.21.13.6937
  Graphics card 2     : Intel Corporation ( 0x8086 ) Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 Version 20.19.15.4474
  Host Name           : Lenovo-PC
  MATLAB Architecture : win64
  MATLAB Entitlement ID: Unknown
  MATLAB Root         : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b
  MATLAB Version      : 9.1.0.441655 (R2016b)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : Version 10.0 (Build 14393)

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Access violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000020  RBX = 0000000000000000
  RCX = 00000000000000a1  RDX = 00000001003c4280
  RSP = 00000000043fb360  RBP = 00000000043fb3c0
  RSI = 000000002aedd590  RDI = 00000000000000a1

   R8 = 0000000000000000   R9 = 0000000000008000
  R10 = 0000000004400000  R11 = 0000000327edab14
  R12 = 00000000043fbfc0  R13 = 00000000e2c041c0
  R14 = 000000000000127f  R15 = 0000000000000000

  RIP = 00000000900c97d7  EFL = 00010206

   CS = 0033   FS = 0053   GS = 002b

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00000000900c97d7                        G:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll+00890839
[  1] 0x000000009006adaf                        G:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll+00503215
[  2] 0x00000000900c97ea                        G:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll+00890858


This error was detected while a MEX-file was running. If the MEX-file
is not an official MathWorks function, please examine its source code
for errors. Please consult the External Interfaces Guide for information
on debugging MEX-files.
```

I have also tested other matlab supported compilers, such as MSVS 2017 and MinGW64. The resulting mex function works well without closing matlab.

Since I have some other codes that can only be compiled using cygwin rather than MSVS nor MinGW64, may I know how to fix the above problem? For these codes, I have successfully used cygwin to get an exe file and it runs properly.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: MATLAB is **very** restrictive about supported compilers. If the compiler is not in the list, you wont be able to use it.

Comment: @AnderBiguri It seems for older version there are ways to use compiler not in the list.

Comment: It is still an unsupported compiler. Someone may have a way to hack to be able to use them, but you won't have guaranteed results. Perhaps you should consider making MVS or mingw  compatible with the other part of your code, instead of matlab compatible with your chosen compiler. In any case, good luck!

Comment: As a workaround you can compile a non-mex .dll from cygwin and use  [loadlibrary](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html)  to load the dll and then you can use [calllib](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/calllib.html) to [call functions in the library](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-functions-in-shared-libraries.html). Other choice is using `system` command to run an exe.

Comment: The g++ cygwin compiler will NOT work. You could have some chance with the cygwin to mingw cross compiler https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2017-10/msg00028.html

Comment: If you have functions which don't work in mingw, they must have dependency on cygwin .dll and probably will be incompatible with a non-cygwin build system which uses Microsoft or mingw compatible components.

Comment: I have used Cygwin to build MEX-files in the past. But not using the `mex` command. I simply compiled as I would any other DLL, linking to the required MATLAB libraries, and setting the extension to be `mexw64`. I'm sure you can configure `mex` to use the Cygwin compiler too. I used the `-mno-cygwin` flag, to not depend on the Cygwin library. If you have need of POSIX functionality this would not work, of course.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @rahnema1 I find that the exe file given by cygwin also needs cygwin1.dll to run properly. Will the non-mex dll file have the same problem? Thanks!

Comment: @matzeri Thanks! The cross compiler x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc works fine for the simple examples as MinGW64 does, but it fails to compile my code.

Comment: @tim18 Agreed. There seems no way to sidestep cygwin1.dll...

Comment: @CrisLuengo It seems -mno-cygwin is an obsolete flag for gcc 3.x. What I want to ask is whether the DLL given by cygwin would be independent of cygwin1.dll, cause the EXE resulting from cygwin can't run without cygwin installed. Thanks!

Comment: @Hugo Yes, it requires cygwin1.dll or maybe other files. It is better to add the cygwin bin folder to the system path. Otherwise you need to add such files in the same folder as the dll/exe.

Comment: @Hugo It seems you are right. It was a while back I used Cygwin. The suggestion I saw was to use `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core` instead of `gcc`. That is equivalent to using the flag in the old days. But again, if you need the POSIX functionality this wouldn't help.